# Will any Target Spells follow Shen across the map if he ult teleports?

Tags: league-of-legends

I do know that if you place a time bomb from Zilean on Shen, he becomes a bomb carrier. There was one time that I shot him with a Janna slow and it followed him up to top lane from bot lane.

**Do Any other spell do that?**

Answer (score 2):

So long as the ability was traveling towards him when he completed his ultimate and teleported across the map, it will chase him down. The same can be said for Summoner Spell Teleport, Twisted Fate's Ultimate, and Recall.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact extent to what can follow Shen across the map. But I know it's possible for some if not most things. For example, Fizz's ultimate can follow him across the map. Video below.

Comment: That.... Is SOOOO HILARIOUS XD